# Sent BTC to Old Output Address

Tags: transactions, output

I sent BTC to an old Output address from a previous transaction and now I do not know where it has gone. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you control that address then you should be able to spend any bitcoins sent to it. Make sure that address and its private key are added to your wallet and you should be able to spend those coins.